# ERROR/InputMethodManagerService(2116): checkCscDefaultIme : mCscDefaultImePackageName is wrong

Tags: android

I'm developing on Android and I got the following error: "ERROR/InputMethodManagerService(2116): checkCscDefaultIme : mCscDefaultImePackageName is wrong."

It's so strange that there's no any search result for this kind of error in Google nor here.

How can I resolve this issue?